# How do I remove the extra right header and whitespace for a datagrid in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, layout, datagrid

I've just started using WPF and working on a DataGrid to store information imported from CSV files. Here is what it looks like after importing some data:

[image: The image of the datagrid, with a red circle around the margin on the right stopping it from fully stretching horizontally.]

The part circled in red is the area I want to remove, as I want the grid to fully stretch to the right if this is possible. I've already set `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` and `ColumnWidth="*"`, so I'm not sure why this extra right margin is appearing. Here's the section of my XAML file for reference. Removing the gridsplitter and stack panel didn't seem to have any effect on this extra part.

```xml
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="100" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="100" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    
        <DataGrid x:Name="TestGrid"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                  ColumnWidth="*"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                  HeadersVisibility="Column"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  GridLinesVisibility="All" />
    
        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Width="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
    
        <ui:SimpleStackPanel Grid.Column="2" Margin="8,5,0,0">
                <Button x:Name="btnAdd"
                        Content="Add File"
                        Margin="0,5,0,0"
                        Style="{StaticResource AccentButtonStyle}"
                        Click="ButtonAddName_Click" />
        </ui:SimpleStackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

How can I change my DataGrid to take up all of the horizontal space?

Comment: You're doing it correctly. I threw your code into a new project and it worked as expected, meaning there was no extra right header or whitespace after the Bundle column.  You might want to start from a new project like I did, and then see where it fails as you add data.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for checking that out. It must be a problem then with the model hooked up and how I handle parsing the data. I'll take a look into that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoops, I figured it out. The "problem" was with the ModernWPF UI library: I realized I hadn't tested adding more rows than it could fit on the screen, as that extra spacing is saved for the scrollbar that appears. For anyone else with the same confusion, this extra space can't be removed as far as I know. For default WPF, the scrollbar doesn't take up space until it appears as an option for those who don't want the spacing.

Answer (score -1):

Set AutoGenerateColumns="False"